# Billing separation with AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services

I run multiple businesses that each use AWS resources. Each business has its own credit card. I'd like to charge each business's card for the resources that business uses. I've created an AWS account for each business but each AWS account belongs to the same AWS organization. I *think* it's useful for them all to belong to the same organization so I can more easily share reserved instances, AMIs and RDS backups between the organizations.

My problem is, that fees for all accounts are billed to the default credit card on the Payer AWS Account account. Is it possible to have charges for each account billed to its own credit card? It looks like I can add a card to each linked account, will that cause the linked account's card to be charged or will all charges still be billed to the Payer Account's card?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this AWS thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=771557) and poking around the console, I believe you cannot use Organizations with consolidated billing disabled.

I think your options are:

- Don't use organisations (you lose the ability to use SCPs and share RIs)
- Use tagging or reporting by account to distribute costs to your other businesses - but you will have to invoice each business / do some other charging mechanism outside of AWS

Comment: Thanks Tim, I hadn't found that thread. That answers my question. Really appreciate your response.